# OpenXava customise

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, frontend, openxava

Im looking at creating a frontend for my Postgresql database, I'am using Drupal 6 (forced to use) I was looking at solutions to allow me rather than create a module which is breaking my head. To code it within the page node, however I found this OpenXava [Link](http://www.openxava.org/web/guest/demos;jsessionid=5A08D453AAFDC68CB3F38A3D2A66D56C) that seems to do it for me which I could just link too. I was wondering does it allow embedding within a page, but mainly is it possible to alter the submit function so that when a record is changed, xyz happens too? (just the basics on if there is a file i just go into add and some code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're developing a Java application you can embed an OpenXava module in your application using a .
You can modify the OpenXava behavior completely, including executing some code on saving, adding validation, even writing your own save action. Have a look at OpenXava doc:
http://www.openxava.org/doc

Comment: I got one issue which I mentioned in the following link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816670/porlets-are-not-creating-while-project-build. Give me some suggestion for the same